# scrapy returning empty json file

Tags: python, scrapy

Im trying to scrape this website but my spider is returning empty json and I cant manage to understand where the problem is. Is there something wrong with my code and/or my approach? Thank you

```
import scrapy
import json

class SrealitySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sreality'
    allowed_domains = ['www.sreality.cz/en']


    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.sreality.cz/api/en/v2/estates?category_main_cb=1&category_type_cb=2&locality_region_id=10&per_page=20&tms=1548939428469",
                            callback=self.parse_id)

    def parse_id(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        estates = data.get("_embedded").get("estates")
        for estate in estates:
            yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.sreality.cz/api{0}?tms=1548942301694".format(estate.get("_links").get("self").get("href")), callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        estate = json.loads(response.body)

        yield {
                 "lat": estate.get("map").get("lat"),
                 "lon": estate.get("map").get("lon"),
                 "title": estate.get("name").get("value").replace(u'\xa0', u' '),
                 "address": estate.get("locality").get("value"),
                 "Price (czk)": estate.get("price_czk").get("value").replace(u'\xa0', u' '),
                 "nearby (m)": {prox.get("name"): prox.get("distance") for prox in estate.get("poi")},
                 "attributes": {attrib.get("name"): attrib.get("value") for attrib in estate.get("items")}

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your `allowed_domains`:  `allowed_domains = ['www.sreality.cz']`
Because spider gets

```
2019-02-01 15:32:50 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.sreality.cz': <GET https://www.sreality.cz/api/en/v2/estates/1034202716?region_tip=220858?tms=1548942301694>
```